# PDF Generation Using CSS and JAVA

Tags: java, css, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF comprised of multiple tables and I want to know if there is a certain way by which I can get to know if the table size will exceed the PDF page size or not. I am using the information to decide wether I will generate the PDF in portrait or landscape mode. Would it be possible to get this size?

Comment: What library are you using for your PDF generation ?

Comment: I am using iTextRenderer for PDF generation.

Comment: If you know the numebr of columns in each table, then you should be able to know the size of resulting page in PDF.

Comment: Would you not get the information from No of Columns * Min Column Width? You might also need to verify w.r.t fonts you intend to use.

Comment: use pdfbox or itextrenderer for pdf generation - basically these are libraries that you could use for pdf generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *know if the table size will exceed the PDF page size*

- The table size is determined from your XHTML Table Content (rows, columns, headers, footers, etc), plus your CSS doc(s) (width, height and border properties).
- The rendering engine (ITextRenderer) only knows your table size, and whether it will fit within a page after it's applied CSS, as part of the process of converting XHTML to rendered output.
- So, if you were to query `ITextRenderer` for this information, you would need to:

  1. Create an `ITextRenderer` instance, pass your `Document` in via `renderer.setDocument()`, and then apply the CSS via `renderer.layout()`, causing all of the layout calculations to occur based upon the original page orientation
  2. Query somehow to determine if the table fits on the page
  3. If it doesn't, switch between portrait/landscape.  But this means changing to a new CSS, setup for a different page shape:

     1. Pick a new CSS, appropriate for the new page orientation and set it within your document
     2. Create a new `ITextRenderer` instance, pass your `Document` in via `renderer.setDocument()`, and then apply the CSS via `renderer.layout()`, causing all of the layout calculations to occur based upon the new page orientation.
     3. Create PDF output via `renderer.createPDF()`.

**Problems:**

- This is inefficient and inelegant processing.
- This is doing things the wrong way around.  Controlling page layout should be part of the design process, and should be reflected in (a) the content generated (XHTML) and (b) the formatting (CSS).  If that's done correctly, there should be no need to do render-time magic to reformat the entire page.
- At step (2), there's no simple query interface that will simply tell you if your table fits within a page.  Instead, you have to query the formatted output blocks, and try to work out for yourself where your table is and whether it fits in a page.  E.g.:

  ```
   BlockBox root = renderer.getRootBox();
   List  pageList = root.getLayer().getPages() 
   PageBox page = (PageBox)pageList.get(2);
   List childBoxList = page.getChildren();
   Box childBox = (Box)childBoxList.get(0);
   // etc... until you locate your table
  ```
- At step (4), ITextRenderer expects your CSS to be linked from within your XHTML document.  That means you first need to modify your XHTML source, then you need to resubmit it to ITextRenderer.

**Suggested Alternative:**

- Do a wireframe/sketch design with 2 scenarios - one for portrait & one for landscape
- Determine the size of elements/rows/columns under the 2 scenarios
- Determine the condition logic under which you would use each scenario, portrait v landscape.  E.g. if I the number of rows is X and the number of columns is Y - then use landscape, ...
- Now create the two CSS files
- Now, when you generate your XHTML, use the condition logic to link to the correct CSS